# efficient way of accessing data grouped by KMeans clusters

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to draw circles around each centroid with radius extending to the furthest out point belonging to each cluster. Right now my circles are drawn with radius extending to the point in the entire training data set furthest from the cluster center

Here is my code:

```
def KMeansModel(n):
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    reduced_train_data = pca.fit_transform(train_data)
    KM = KMeans(n_clusters=n)
    KM.fit(reduced_train_data)
    plt.plot(reduced_train_data[:, 0], reduced_train_data[:, 1], 'k.', markersize=2)
    centroids = KM.cluster_centers_
    # Plot the centroids as a red X
    plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1],
                marker='x', color='r')
    for i in centroids:
        print np.max(metrics.pairwise_distances(i, reduced_train_data))
        plt.gca().add_artist(plt.Circle(i, np.max(metrics.pairwise_distances(i, reduced_train_data)), fill=False))
    plt.show()

out = [KMeansModel(n) for n in np.arange(1,16,1)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
metrics.pairwise_distances(i, reduced_train_data)
```

you calculate the distance from all the training points, and not only the training points from the relevant class. In order to find the positions of the points from the training data that correspond to class `ind`, you can do

```
np.where(KM.labels_==ind)[0]
```

Thus, inside the for loop

```
for i in centroids:
```

you need to access to the training points from the specific class. This will do the job:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def KMeansModel(n):
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    reduced_train_data = pca.fit_transform(train_data)
    KM = KMeans(n_clusters=n)
    KM.fit(reduced_train_data)
    plt.plot(reduced_train_data[:, 0], reduced_train_data[:, 1], 'k.', markersize=2)
    centroids = KM.cluster_centers_
    # Plot the centroids as a red X
    plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1],
                marker='x', color='r')
    for ind,i in enumerate(centroids):
        class_inds=np.where(KM.labels_==ind)[0]
        max_dist=np.max(metrics.pairwise_distances(i, reduced_train_data[class_inds]))
        print(max_dist)
        plt.gca().add_artist(plt.Circle(i, max_dist, fill=False))
    plt.show()

out = [KMeansModel(n) for n in np.arange(1,16,1)]
```

And here is one of the figures that I get using the code:

[image]